# Why isn't Mailchimp's email form inheriting my website's style?

Tags: css, mailchimp

I embedded Mailchimp's Email subscription form into my website builder hosted by Payhip and cannot seem to get the embed code to properly inherit my website's style (which Mailchimp claims should happen automatically... it does not).

As a consequence, I've brute forced a bunch of !importants to get the embed code to get the correct style, and it all seems to work *except* for the border.

Can anyone figure out why no border shows up? I increased the border-width to 10px to make it super obvious.

The code below should have the border around the red Subscribe button to be 10px and yellow, and then hovering over the button should get it to become 1px and white. Nothing happens though.

Website is at: https://hiphopondapullup.com.

```
<div id="mc_embed_shell">
      <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-061523.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <style type="text/css">

#mc-embedded-subscribe { 
    border-width: 10px !important;
    border-color: #ffff00 !important;
    border-radius: 0.3rem !important;     
    background-color: #e30f11 !important;
    color: #121212 !important;     
    font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    text-transform: none !important;
    line-height: 1.2em !important;
    letter-spacing: 0em !important;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe:hover { 
    border-color: #ffffff !important;
    border-width: 1px !important;}


        /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
           We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>


<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="https://hiphopondapullup.us13.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=72af4cf5a706e12fa4f5180bc&amp;id=139e61457f&amp;f_id=00f97ae4f0" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

            <div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span></label><input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" required="" value=""></div>
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear foot">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display: none;"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    <div aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
        /* real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups */
        <input type="text" name="b_72af4cf5a706e12fa4f5180bc_139e61457f" tabindex="-1" value="">
    </div>
        <div class="optionalParent">
            <div class="clear foot">
                <input type="submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" value="Subscribe" >

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[3]='ADDRESS';ftypes[3]='address';fnames[4]='PHONE';ftypes[4]='phone';fnames[5]='BIRTHDAY';ftypes[5]='birthday';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script></div>
```

Comment: `border: 0 none` is applied via the rule with selector `#mc_embed_signup .button`,  and that has a higher specificity that your rule with the selector `#mc-embedded-subscribe`. The `!important` in your rule _should_ still overwrite this, but I am guessing the way you are embedding this, influences the cascade somehow here. Can you put this into a proper stylesheet, instead of hacking it into a `style` element directly in the document, and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and help! As a new user, I'm super impressed by this platform :)

I noticed the thing with the `border: 0 none` when using Chrome's inspect tool so I tried something like `#mc_embed_signup.button {border: 1px transparent !important;}` which also didn't work for some reason. It's driving me insane!

I couldn't find how to edit Mailchimp's stylesheet, is that even something that's possible?

Comment: I'd start by putting that link element into the `head` where it belongs, instead of having it somewhere in the middle of your body content. (Browsers are quite error tolerant, but I couldn't say if this somehow influences the cascade here.)

Comment: Sorry how do I find where the `head` is? I'm using a website builder similar to Shopify and simply copy pasted the above code into the "Embed Code Section" of the website builder. In case it wasn't glaringly apparent, I am a total noob at this.

Comment: I wouldn't know, don't know your tool. But the content of https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-061523.css isn't too big, so you could simply copy&paste that into your own stylesheet, modify it accordingly, and then remove the embed of the original stylesheet from MailChimp altogether.

Comment: That's actually genius! I think I'm at the final step now. I've just done your suggestion but the stylesheet doesn't seem to carry over, any idea why?

Comment: If you use Chrome dev tools (F12), on the right there is a tab for computed styles that shows you the whole cascading hierarchy and which styles are being overridden or are overriding others. Very helpful for troubleshooting this sort of problem.

Comment: Okay I tried copy pasting my changes to my own stylesheet but still the same problem — modifying the border color doesn't seem to do anything and I can't figure out where it's been overridden. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to find the problem with the Force element state tool in dev tools